# Delta table linked to sql table

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, mssql-jdbc

I'm new on databricks and spark, we create delta table using data from sql. Theese table are kind of mirrored. Basicalli if I insert a new row to sql it affects delta, I can even insert from databricks having sql updated, but deleting is allowed only from sql.
By the way,  I don't understand how it works, if I create a delta table with this command the delta and sql table are linked

```
spark.sql("""
 create table IF NOT EXISTS dbname.delta_table
 using org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
 OPTIONS (
   url '""" + sql_url + """',
   dbtable 'dbname.sql_table',
   user '""" + sql_user + """',
   password '""" + sql_password + """',
   TRUNCATE true
 )
""");
```

But if I try with pyspark, there's no link between table

```
spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url_sql) \
  .option("dbtable", sql_table) \
  .option("user", sql_user) \
  .option("password", sql_password) \
  .option("truncate", True) \
  .load() \
  .write \
  .saveAsTable(delta_table)
```

I would like to know how to get the same result with pyspark and how to get more documentation about it, I didn't find what I was looking for, I don't know what kind of relationship there's between table and the keyword related to this.
Thanks for help
Sergio

I've been looking online all day to find the correct topic but I didn't find anything

Comment: It seems that your first SQL Statement is just trying to create a table in the SQL Server. It doesn't create a delta table. Does the SQL Statement run successfully and actually create a table?

Comment: Your second command reads the same table from the SQL Server and tries to create a delta table with the name defined by `delta_table`. The `SQL` and `PySpark` scripts are doing two different things. The `SQL` one is creating a table in SQL Server (with no schema?) and the `pyspark` one is reading the same table from SQL Server and saving it as a `delta` table

Comment: Actually the SQL script creates a delta table on databricks using the sql table

Comment: Are you sure? In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using) it specifies that if  you want to create a delta table, you should either say `USING delta` or nothing at all. Can you point to the documentation where it tells you that you can create a delta table with that SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing different things:

- First SQL statements creates a metadata entry in the hive metastore that points to the SQL database.  So when you read from it, Spark under the hood connects via JDBC protocol, and loads the data.
- In the second approach you're actually loading data from database, and create a managed table that is stored in Delta format (default format).  This table is the snapshot of the SQL server at the time of execution.

Really, if you want to create a table as in your first case, you just need to continue to use `spark.sql`.